# How to allign left and right alignments same in bootstrap css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to design a form with two divisions, based on google i was able to do that, but the problem is left and right alignments are not equal, right side there was a lot of space is coming.  below is my trail , can any body suggest what needs to be done for this adjustment? is it the right approach or not?

I am trying this in Asp.net MVC.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
            <div class="row row-centered">
                <div class="centred">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-centered">
                        <label class="control-label">UserName</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">PhoneNumber</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">TextArea</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Address</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Location</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">City</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Fiber</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">State</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Town</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">PostalCode</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Pincode</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you a personnalized stylesheet ?

Comment: @Louis D: no i didn't change any thing,trying from sample from different posts

Comment: But what is the style for `.controls` for example ? It will be more simple to help youif you make a jsfiddle.